# Is there a way to create "render texture" in Bevy?

Tags: rendering, textures, bevy

I'd like to create a [portal-like effect](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuQao3hEKfs) using [Bevy](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy). It seems Unity has a [render texture](https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/class-RenderTexture.html) to achieve that.

Is there a way to do the equivalent in Bevy? If not, is there a plan to support that in the future?

Comment: Do you mean something like that: https://mrk.sed.pl/bevy-showcase/#render_to_texture

Comment: @frankenapps Thank you for the comment. I think I need the ability to render what a camera sees to a texture. I don't know if the example (your link) is doing so... do you have any idea how it's created (or any source code)?

Comment: The code for the posted sample can be found here: https://github.com/mrk-its/bevy/blob/render_to_texture/examples/3d/render_to_texture.rs
If you want to render the camera viewport to a texture you can find some information here: https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/issues/1207
It seems to more or less work for jpg files as of now: https://github.com/rmsc/bevy/blob/render_to_file/examples/3d/render_to_file.rs

Comment: @frankenapps Ohhh.. thank you! I will check it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has become very easy with Bevy 0.8's [Camera Driven Rendering](https://bevyengine.org/news/bevy-0-8/#camera-driven-rendering)

You simply assign an image render target to a camera:

```rust
camera.target = RenderTarget::Image(image_handle);
```

For a complete example see the official [render to texture example](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/latest/examples/3d/render_to_texture.rs).